# UNITY 3D - Saving last scene

Tags: unity, c#, javascript

I can't find working solution for this problem anywhere. Here is what I'm trying to do:

My Android game contains 10+ levels, user quits game on level 2. Next time user starts game it load level 2 automatically. Thats all I want, no need to save objects, just load last scene. I prefer simple javascript, but examples on the unity tutorials confuse me. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

When player quit from game you should save current level number so when player will come again in game should load last current level.

when player finish current level save next level number so when player quit and run game again loaded next level.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public enum Situation{None,Exit,Lose,Win
    };
    public Situation mycase;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Application.LoadLevel (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int LevelNumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex;
        switch(mycase){
        case Situation.Exit:
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Level", LevelNumber); //Save Level number
            Application.Quit ();
            mycase = Situtation.None;
            break;
        case Situation.Lose:
            Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);//Reset Level
            mycase = Situtation.None;
            break;
        case Situation.Win:
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Level", LevelNumber + 1); //Save Level next number
            Application.LoadLevel (LevelNumber + 1); //Load NextLevel
            mycase = Situtation.None;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to use it or it doesn't work. I add this to an empty object and level 1 loads every 5 seconds.

Comment: What those tick boxes are for?

Comment: because you should add scenes from File > BuildSetting >>Add Open scene.I use tick boxes for check condition this is mean when condition is true for example if Lose is true Reset Level

Comment: All the scenes are add. I appreciate your work man, and would like to get this working. Because now it just glitches out.

Should I add this to all scenes or one is enough?

Comment: Using boolean flags for chain if else checking is not a good practice. Use an Enum instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you need just one interger value be saved and loaded.

In your scene load method, use these lines. Put your first game scene index instead of 2.

```
if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("current_level") == null)
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("current_level", 2);//assuming level 0 is splash screen, level 1 is main menu and level 2 is first scene. Change as your need
}
Application.LoadLevel(PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("current_level"));
```

On every scene use the below method in an active object.

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("current_level", Application.loadedLevel);
}
```

`PlayerPrefs` is not suggested in large scale data handling. Use [binaryformatter](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934), [xmlserializer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer) etc for that purposes. You will get more control over data.

If you are not using `Application.Quit ()` for game exit then use it. Or you can put the line in `OnApplicationQuit ()` to `Start ()` on an active object in all scene. That way even if you don't quit the game, just going into the scene will be saved.

[Switch to JS to see how to write JS function which is written in C#](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html)

Comment: Scene 1 keeps reloading :/

Comment: You used the second method in all scenes?

Comment: I put the first one method in first scene and the second method in every other scene. It get's stuck on scene 1. My all other scripts are in js.

Comment: It's almost same in js, I assume you know how to covert the small thing that's not same. Are you quitting the scene with `Application.Quit ();` ?

Comment: I'm not using `Application.Quit ();` and i don't know how to convert this code to js.